# initialise superclass array in subclass (java)

Tags: java, android, arrays, oop

I am new to JAVA / Android programming and have a small problem.

I created in a Superclass a Array and wanted to initialize it in multiple subclasses. But when I try to initialize it, it says it's not possible.

My code:

```
public abstract class Fragen {

 String[] Deutsch;
 String[] Slowakisch;

static int Anzahl;
Random random;
int randNumber;

byte Fächer;

public String displayQuestion()
{

    //TODO Fach abfragen
    randNumber = random.nextInt(Anzahl);

    return Slowakisch[randNumber];

}

public boolean correctAnswer(String answer)
{
    //TODO Fächer +/-

    if(answer.equals(Deutsch[randNumber]))
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}
}
```

(Superclass)

```
 public class Lektion1 extends Fragen
{
    private Lektion1()
    {
        super();
        Anzahl = 60;
        //Deutsch = new String[];
        Deutsch = {"",""};
        Slowakisch = {"",""};
    }
}
```

(Subclass)

Kind regards
Thomas

Comment: Kindly post exact error

Comment: Do yourself a favour and avoid fiddling with arrays - this is so 1990's ! Use say `ArrayList<String>`instead!

Comment: @Gyro He says he is new to programming, let him learn to understand memory usage correctly! Not like some new programmers who don't know what memory is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Lektion1 extends Fragen
{
    private Lektion1()
    {
        super();
        Anzahl = 60;
        //Deutsch = new String[];
        Deutsch = new String[]{"", ""};
        Slowakisch = new String[]{"", ""};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constructor in your super class and initialize that array there:

```
public abstract class Fragen {
    ...
    public Fragen() {
        Deutsch = new String[];
    }
    ...
}
```

---

***alternative***

or if your fields have appropriate access modifiers, then you can also access them using `super` keyword

```
public abstract class Fragen {
    public String[] Deutsch;
    ...
    ...
}
```

and in base class:

```
public class Lektion1 extends Fragen {
    private Lektion1()
    {
        super();
        Anzahl = 60;
        super.Deutsch = new String[];
        Deutsch = {"",""};
        Slowakisch = {"",""};
    }
}
```

Comment: In the superclass you don’t know how long arrays will be required, so there’s no point in instantiating them without input from the subclass. Whether you want to put `super.` in front of `Deutsch` is matter of taste — it works without and with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For a conrete answer to your concrete question, @MrQuattro’s answer is of course correct and fulfilling.

That said, if you want to learn more of object-oriented design, I still myself like the ideas from my original answer. You can of course throw away or use as you see fit: I propose that it will be more convenient to keep the German and the Slovakian word together, so I’d make a class `Frage` to hold one word (or phrase or expression) in both languages.

Next I’d want to make a constructor in `Fragen` that accepts all the `Frage` objects, for instance as varargs (you should learn about those). This will allow the `Lektion1` constructor to contain just

```
super(new Frage("", ""), new Frage("", ""), new Frage("", ""));
```

`Fragen` can count, so you don’t need to: the superclass constructor will set `anzahl` (please use lowercase `a` for a variable) to the number of questions received.

If you want to take it a step further, the `Frage` class could also be given the responsibility of checking whether an answer is correct.

**Link:** [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)